# Typescript lambda function with logical OR

Tags: typescript

Sorry to bring this up with what some might consider easy syntax but I am having trouble wrapping my head around this.One => this.IsWeird

So I have some code:

```
get items(): readonly TodoItem[] {
    return this.list.items.filter(item => this.showComplete || !item.complete);
} 

showComplete: boolean = false;
```

Apparently this is the equivalent of :

```
get items(): readonly TodoItem[] {
   if (this.showComplete == true) {
       return this.list.items;
   }

   if (this.showComplete == false) {
       return this.list.items.filter(item => !item.complete);
   }  
} 

showComplete: boolean = false;
```

The '||' operator in the lambda function is what throws me off.
What operator would I use if I wanted the reverse to happen, say if I wanted to return the items that are not complete if showComplete was true? Thanks for looking, sorry if this should be apparent to me.

Comment: can you post  more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical OR operator `a || b` can be used as a shorthand in JavaScript for `if a is not true, evaluate b`. It works due to short-circuit evaluation, which means that if `a` is true, it does not need to evaluate the rest of the expression as it is irrelevant, the expression will be true anyway. However, if `a` is false, it will execute `b` to fully evaluate the expression.

In the `.filter()` method, if `this.showComplete` is true, it will return true for every entry (i.e. it will only evaluate `this.showComplete`). If `this.showComplete` is false, it will evaluate the whole expression and return `!item.complete`.

To change the response to do the opposite as you ask, you could change it to:

```
return this.list.items.filter(item => this.showComplete && !item.complete);
```

`a && b` is also a shorthand expression in JavaScript for `if a is true, evaluate b`. So in this case, when `this.showComplete` is true, the second part of the expression will also be evaluated. When `this.showComplete` is false, nothing will be returned as every evaluation will return false.